# iOS App publishing to iTunes Connect - No application records were found

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am having trouble publishing my iOS app which is signed with a valid certificate for distribution and using the correct bundle identifier. When attempting to validate the app in Organizer I get the following error message, "No application records were found. Applications must be ready for upload on iTunes Connect before they can be validated or submitted from within Xcode." and also on iTunes Connect the status is "Waiting For Upload". I have been through everything and cannot see anything in the the project build settings that could be causing this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you signing in to itunes connect and the xcode submission process with the same account?

Comment: Yeah just now realised that. Thanks.

Comment: Here is the detailed answer on the issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30110757/xcode-error-when-uploading-to-app-store-no-suitable-application-records-were-f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to log in to iTunes connect with the same account that you are trying to submit under in order for Apple to see the Application Record you are trying to submit.

Comment: Thank you for that, was using my dev center account. It is submitted now.

Answer (score 1):

## App Status

Another reason for this problem is if your app has a status of `Prepare For Upload` rather than `Waiting For Upload`.

For more info, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22279158/642706) on another similar question.

Answer (score 0):

changing the app status in iTunesConnect is the key for resolving this error.