# Xcode 5 - "No application records were found" when trying to Validate an Archive

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode5, app-store-connect

Hi Folks:    Just a person (not a company) trying to submit an app, developed with Xcode 5 to the App Store.

Developer.apple.com > IOS Dev Center > iTunes Connect > Manager you Apps > Add New Apps > Click here to register new bundle > Click on AppIDs to see what I have previously registered.

If I had 10 reputations on Stackoverflow, I'd post a screenshot. (I will if I can).
Summary is that iTunes Connect says:

- Prefix is C58H638D3X
- ID is EdAndJ.tiltr9999
- Identifier = C58H638D3X.EdAndJ.tiltr9999

So I go back to Xcode5 and I change the Bundle ID to: I tried both:

- C58H638D3X.EdAndJ.tiltr9999, and
- EdAndJ.tiltr9999

I then manually deleted the build directory and re-built and re-archived. No errors or warnings.
Archive shows the correct"Identifier".   But when I Validate, I get a "No Application Records were found".

I have read in one articles that this may be because iTunes Connect is not in a state of "waiting for my application"... but I do not know how to put it in that state (if that's my issue in the first place).

This is a duplicate of a question I posed earlier today but now that I know more, I re-posed it with more information.    Thanks to all those who answer... you make the world a better place :).

-Ed

Comment: Did you create a distribution profile for your app.? You need to create a new profile just for the app. Name it as the name of your app if you want and then download it. Find it in your download directory and double click on it and then it will open up with xcode. Then your project I think it is the section below your profiles, you need to select it as the app profile. That will do the job. If you need help with finding things in Dev center and getting it done let me know.

Comment: Thanks @XCodeMonkey... I went to my identities and created a Distribution Certificate and generated a public-key... downloaded etc.   I then created a distribution profile, downloaded it, restarted Xcode and confirmed via Xcode > Preferences > Account > View Details... that the new DistributionProfile was selected.    SAME ERROR when trying to Validate the archive.. No Application records were found.   :(

Comment: i asked you to go to the proviso sing profiles and create a distribution profile for your app. Not the other way around. Oh by the way did you ever go to itunes connect and added the info for your new app?

Comment: I did what you said but because I did not yet have a certificate, it took me thru that process first.   And Yes... my app is listed under Identifiers > App IDs (as I mentioned in my original post).   I wish Could post screenshots...

Comment: Did you go to itunes connect site and add your app in there. When you add a new app it asks you hot a bunch of stuff. Then when you finish your app will be waiting to uoad binary. If you have done that and created specific distribution as I mentioned, then xcode will recognize the whole thing. Go to itunes and select add new app.

Comment: So people say "iTunes" but really is it https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/identifiers/bundle/bundleList.action    right?    I get there by going to Developer.apple.come > iOS Dev >  Certificates, Identifiers and Profiles.   This is the same place I get to if I go to Developer.appl > iOS Dev > iTunes Connect > Manager your apps > Add new app > Click here for new BundleID > AppIDs.   If this is the place you are talking about.. YES... my app is registered there... I'm at eight replies... at 10 I get to post pictures / screenshots :)

Comment: did you go iTunes connect and added you app? https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/wo/4.0 click on this link and then go to manage my your apps and then from the top select add new app. did you do this already?

Comment: I believe I have solved it and will post a new post with instructions for beginners.   Thanks for all your help. See below but what I did...

Comment: I'm glad you were able to fix the issue. That's the whole idea of being in here. To help each other. Good luck.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As you already mentioned and as per the documentation - [App Distribution Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/SubmittingYourApp/SubmittingYourApp.html)

> Important: You can’t validate your app unless the app record in iTunes Connect is in the “Waiting for Upload” or later state

After you add a new app in iTunes connect there will be an amber light along with its status. It will most likely read **"Prepare For Upload"**. To get it to the **"Waiting For Upload"** state click view details for the app and in the top right there should be a blue button that says **"Ready to Upload Binary"**. Click this and follow the given directions.

Comment: Oooooo... I so want this to work... can you be more specific on which web-page I would find this blue button? How do I get there?   I tried here: https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/identifiers/bundle/bundleList.action but that's not where it is....

Comment: Log into iTunes connect. Click on the manage your apps module. You will be presented with apps you have created. Select the app then click view details. What status is it showing? If you have not created the app then do this first by clicking on "Add New App" found top left blue button. This is all in the manage your apps module in iTunes connect.

Comment: You are looking in Certs and identifiers in the member centre of the dev site. You need to log into iTunes connect. Sounds to me like you are yet to 'add new app' to create an iTunes record. Must do this first and make sure you have your large icon and a couple of screen shots ready to go.

Comment: *(&#$%*($^%&&*()@#_*$&)&*^$(%*)$%*(&)#$%^)#@*($^*@#$  I used to work for Microsoft for 13 years....   OY.... APPLE NEEDS UI HELP!    I Logged into iTunes Connect.  Add New App > Click here to specify your identifier... this opens a new tab and puts you in developer.apple.com. I registered my app **BUT NEVER KNEW TO GO BACK TO THE PRECEDING ITUNES CONNECT TAB TO COMPLETE THE APP REGISTRATION **

Comment: I believe this will now work.  As I state above, iTunes Connect opened a new tab to create the BundleID but I never went back tot he Connect tab to complete the app registrations, submit screenshots etc.     VERY BAD User Interface !!      But it looks like I'm on my way. I will post another article for folks doing this for the first time... I'm an engineer and it still took me 3 days to figure this out !!

Answer (score 8):

Go to itunes connect.
Click on your app.
Click More.
Click About this App.
Select your bundle identifier.
Now go back and validate the app again.
It should be fine.

Comment: this makes my blood pressure at normal state.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem. When in iTunes Connect, select your app, click edit information and on the bottom of the page it has a button (Ready to upload binary) click that, follow through the process and then XCode will find the pending application

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue while I was updating my old application in iTunes Connect. I 
resolved that by putting some work by gone through some posts on web. We have 
one application in live store with one bundle id (com.sample.AppOne). We need 
to update the app to next version.

Then I gave bundle id as (com.sample.AppNine) which does not match with the bundle in iTunes Connect earlier. So while updating the app in iTunes Connect we should give same bundle id which we gave for old version.This solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

As per new structure of apple deployment , go to itunesconnect > My apps > Select app > select Features in menu bar > Go to encryption at left side menu.

Choose the appropriate option , here you the site will instruct you to put one option in info.plist as per your selection.

Just follow that steps , and you are good to go.