# error when archive and validate a new application version IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

how to solve the error in ther following image , when archive and validate a new application version??
[image]

Comment: Which Xcode you are using?

Comment: Version 8.2 beta (8C23)

Comment: Change your bundle name to something else that is unique.

Comment: I am sure it is unique

Comment: I changed the bundle name, but the problem  it is still appearing .

Answer (score 0):

Your bundle identifier is invalid. Replace it with proper bundle identifier. You can change it like this:

[image]

> Edit: You must have an iTunes Connect app record to validate and upload your app to iTunes Connect. The bundle ID you enter in iTunes Connect must match the bundle ID in your Xcode project.

Refer this [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/UploadingYourApptoiTunesConnect/UploadingYourApptoiTunesConnect.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH36-SW2).
Also, this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22279158/5620628).

Comment: are you sure from that? did you face this  problem  Previously?

Comment: It's better that you use your own bundle identifier. Currently, you're using AFNetworking ones, which is not yours. It will most probably solve your problem.

Comment: I changed the bundle name, but the problem it is still appearing .

Comment: Your new bundle identifier is?

Comment: Found your problem. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

yes, I found the problem. i make a new project and copy for all classes and files  into  new project, and then validate and upload  api  without any  problem.

I think the problem in plist file, it is  corrupted. for that   I make  copy for this file from test folder  into  Project  folder