# Xcode error when uploading to App Store: "No suitable application records were found"

Tags: xcode, app-store, ionic-framework

I'm using Ionic to build an html app for iOS. I've registered an app on iTunes Connect.

All goes well in Xcode until I upload to the App Store. I get the following error:

> **iTunes Store operation failed.**
>   No suitable application records were found. Verify your bundle identifier 'com.iconicframework.app315125' is correct.

[image: iTunes Store operation failed]

Comment: You should validate within xcode before uploading.

Comment: I'm getting this for Pods using in project. For eg. Alamofire pod having bundle id : com.cocoapods.Alamofire.. How to fix this?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

I suspect you should not be calling your app "com.ionicframework.app315125". That looks like a leftover name from an example project.

You need to create a new Bundle Identifier in the Developer portal:

[image]

Then choose it when you "Create New App" in iTunesConnect:

[image]

For me, I'd pick com.maniac-games.lowdown.

Comment: Cheers Almo, I figured as much that this is the right track but still don't know where that name should go on iTunesConnect. Thank you!

Comment: You also need to add the app to your iTunes connect account.

Answer (score 32):

Maybe you need to review [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppStoreDistributionTutorial/CreatingYourTeamProvisioningProfile/CreatingYourTeamProvisioningProfile.html) document.

In other words:

1. You must go to developer.apple.com and create a provisioning profile and bundle id.
2. Assign devices to provisioning
3. Then ... enter itunesconnect and create app and assign your bundle id.
4. Enter to Xcode and reload provisioning files.
5. Enter to Targets files and select provisioning.
6. Product -> Archive and go on :)

Comment: Don't forget select as an answer !! You are welcome ! (whatever you want) :)

Comment: Almo had a faster response and has pretty images so they get the answer but i'll find ways to reward you in this life or the next! :P

Comment: Thanks, I did not know i have to create ap in itunes connect

Answer (score 13):

For those who are seeing this answer after June 2020, I'm running XCode 11, and I got this error because I forgot to make an app in App Store Connect:

https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/

If you have XCode 11, under "Signing & Capabilities" -> "Automatically manage signing", it'll solve 90% of the problem for you, but the other 10% is just logging into your developer account, going to App Store Connect -> Apps -> (Blue "+" icon), then select a Bundle ID that matches your Bundle Identifier back in XCode.

Comment: This was the same for me!  I had the app name in the developer account, but I had to add it to App Store connect as well.

Answer (score 9):

I was also facing same issue..I fixed it by creating an app on itunesConnect before uploading app.
once you created app on itunesconnect. you should not get this error anymore.

there should be some authentication and a place to store your build. and if you don't have an app on itunesconnect with same bundle id it will not let you upload your app.

Answer (score 6):

For me the problem was that the user used for uploading was set to Limited Access instead of Full Access. Fixed that via App Information > Additional Information > Edit User Access. Took me several hours to track down! It would of course have been helpful to get a slightly more detailed error message.

Comment: This must be Full Access in App information > Edit User Access and select Full Access

Answer (score 5):

I received the same error on multiple attempts.

Follow below step: 
1) Create AppID inside [developer site](https://developer.apple.com) `Identifiers -> IDS.` 
2) Create Provisioning Profiles Certificate Provisioning `Profiles - > Distribution.` 
3) Create App inside [iTunes](https://itunesconnect.apple.com) and Give name of app, select Bundle identifier of app and just click on Create app. 
4) Inside xcode select `Product -> Archive` wait few minute then open Organizer(`Windows -> Organizer`) and show app in Organizer, Click on Upload to App store  
5) Successfully you have upload app in app store.

Answer (score 3):

Set the Same name.this way is success.

[image: step1]

[image: step2]

[image: step3]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, after a while checking I added my app's details into [AppstoreConnect](http://appstoreconnect.apple.com) then it was fixed!

Don't forget that at first you need to define a new bundle identifier and provisioning profile.

Answer (score 1):

For the ones who get this error **on an app which was sumbitable previously**, **please log in to iTunesConnect / AppStoreConnect** and **accept** the latest Terms of Services or **whatever legal message you have to approve**.

Note that if you are **working with an external publisher** you need **someone whose account has the highest permission** to have the message appearing.

Answer (score 0):

Well what soloved the issue for me was changing the bundleID when the pop up (while validating) comes up to the actual bundleID which was not right at that time but is now fixed and my app is one the way to the Appstore!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new Bundle Identifier in the Developer portal(https://developer.apple.com) **like create your app in myapps with same Bundle Identifier**

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:
Go to xcode > Preferences > Login with your email again and fetch the certificates