# iTunes Store operation Failed. No suitable application records werer found... in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm using Xcode 8 to submit my App to App Store. And I'm using automatically manage signing.Then I got this error.
[image: error message]

Then I follow [Xcode error when uploading to App Store: "No suitable application records were found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30110757/xcode-error-when-uploading-to-app-store-no-suitable-application-records-were-f) to add an APP ID on Apple's Developer Center.Then I got the Error of this
[image]

So I go to [An App ID with Identifier '' is not available. Please enter a different string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20565565/an-app-id-with-identifier-is-not-available-please-enter-a-different-string) ,seems the error was not exists in Xcode.

I'm confused, Is it possible to fix this by Xcode 8's "automatic signing"? Or I have to do this manually?

Comment: can you please tell me mac os x version?

Comment: @Wos It's macOS Sierra (10.12)

Comment: may i know that you have create an app on iTunes connect the app submitting. Or Try to upload app on xcode 7.2

Comment: Please tell me it's working or not if you are uploading app on xcode 7.2

Comment: @Wos I'm trying to upload the app in Xcode8. And [This my source code](https://github.com/Stanley-Tian/TrackTV), if you need to take a look

Comment: @Wos Sorry, I haven't used Xcode 7.x since I'm new in ios development

Comment: have you create app on iTunes connect?

Comment: i check your code setup. It's fine

Comment: @Wos No I haven't. By the way ... what is iTunes connect?

Comment: Oh. If you have upload app than you have to 99$ apple developer account. Apple will provide two type account one is not create a certificate and other one is for app store.

Comment: do login in https://itunesconnect.apple.com/itc/static/login?appIdKey=e0b80c3bf78523bfe80974d320935bfa30add02e1bff88ec2166c6bd5a706c42&view=1&path=%2FWebObjects%2FiTunesConnect.woa%3F

Comment: @Wos Yeah, I'm using my friend's developer account

Comment: If you have 99$ apple developer account than this will permission to login other wise you have to purchase an membership login

Comment: @Wos Yes I logged in the system, and trying to add a new app, But I still can't set my app ID(com.tmt.tv). As I said, I can't even add it to the developer account

Comment: Follow this link http://clearbridgemobile.com/how-to-submit-an-app-to-the-app-store/

Comment: http://codewithchris.com/submit-your-app-to-the-app-store/

Comment: @Wos Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please tell me if you have still any difficulty

Comment: If you find solution than i post this in answer and please mark as compete vote

Comment: @Wos The tutorial is easy to follow, I just committed my app for review, thanks again!