# XCode Submit: No suitable application records were found

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, validation, archive

I am trying to upload my iOS  app to the mac osx app store. I have followed all directions and confirmed the following:

I have created an app id and bundle identifier in the iOS developer portal.

I have linked this app id/identifier to the app I created in itunes connect.
     Yes, bundle IDs match.
     Yes, I have set the app to "1.0 Prepare for Submission" status.

I have signed my app in xcode with the developer certificate, have all correct identifiers such as version number, copyright, name, etc. All is correct.

If I archive and then validate I get "No suitable application records were found." Same for Submit button.
     Yes, I have tried the application loader, same error.
     Yes, I am using my correct itunes connect account (I only have one).

Any suggestions? Typical pitfalls for this seem to be not creating ituens connect or dev portal identifiers, not setting status to "waiting for upload", and using an incorrect developer ID account. I have verified I am using all this correct data.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30110757/xcode-error-when-uploading-to-app-store-no-suitable-application-records-were-f

Comment: I see this post, but without any solution

Comment: are you added the bundle identifier in your itunesconnect.apple.com

Comment: then do onething bro, change the bundle Identifier in developer.apple.com and add that identifier to xcode and itunes connect and try once, best of luck

Comment: i am confused here "I am trying to upload my ios app to the mac osx app store"...!

Comment: i am confused here "I am trying to upload my ios app to ituens  app store"...! – raki 11 mins ago

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik
 I did everything without any  solution

Comment: Make sure you are using the same team/account as used in iTunes Connect.