# xcode itunes submit error ITMS-90277

Tags: xcode, macos, itunes

I have created a new app in itunes connect with bundle id: `com.mydomain.myapp-osx`.
Now, after archiving the app and submitting it to itunes, xcode says:

> ERROR ITMS-90277: "Invalid Bundle Identifier. The application bundle
>   contains a tool or framework $(PRODUCT_NAME)
>   [com.mydomain.myapp-osx.pkg/Payload/liturgia
>   osx.app/Contents] using the bundle identifier
>   '$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)', which is not a valid bundle
>   identifier." ERROR ITMS-90277: "Invalid Bundle Identifier. The
>   application bundle contains a tool or framework $(PRODUCT_NAME)
>   [com.mydomain.myapp-osx.pkg/Payload/liturgia
>   osx.app/Contents] using the bundle identifier
>   '$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)', which is not a valid bundle
>   identifier."

What is this error all about?
I have tried editing plist.info and instead of putting  `$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)` I hard code the bundle id as `com.mydomain.myapp-osx` but the same error occurs.

Comment: Is it related to this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30110757/xcode-error-when-uploading-to-app-store-no-suitable-application-records-were-f/30110914#30110914

Comment: @user2070775 Did you find a solution to this