# Archive validation failed with errors: iTunes Store operation failed

Tags: ios, cocoapods, archive, pubnub

I use PubNub in my project. I am sure the bundle id from iTunes Connect and and my project are same. When I validate my project, I get this error.[image]

Comment: I doubt this is PubNub issue. Have you tried uploading without PubNub included to see if it succeeds?

Comment: You seem to have an incorrect bundle identifier in your project, so no matching app can be found in iTunesConnect. Your bundle ID should be something like "com.yourdomain.yourapp"

Comment: @CraigConover. Thanks for your reply. No, but I uploaded my project to apple store last week, and it worked. I use NSString *identifier = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier] to print my Bundle id, and it's the same as the one in iTunes Connect. Besides, the development team is right........I just wonder where does the 'org.cocapods.PubNub' come from......Or if I set something wrong????

Comment: I'm just fairly confident that it is not due t PubNub code, but I could be wrong. Just never seen this before (3.5+ years) but there is always a first time ;) Try this SO post and see if it provides any insights: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30110757/xcode-error-when-uploading-to-app-store-no-suitable-application-records-were-f

Comment: @CraigConover   Thank you, Craig~

Comment: @CraigConover I find the problem. It's not about bundle id. I forgot to add icon for ipad pro. Really don't know why Xcode showed me this alert. Thank you for your help and your patience~

Comment: No worries. I was pretty sure it was something unrelated to PubNub. Xcode showing unhelpful messages ;) 
You should post this as an answer to your question here.

Answer (score 0):

On behalf of user7954458...

I find the problem. It's not about bundle id. I forgot to add icon for ipad pro