# No suitable application records were found. Verify your bundle identifier is correct. App Loader is missing

Tags: ios, swift, app-store-connect

I want to load my app build to itunes connect, but I get this error:
"No suitable application records were found. Verify your bundle identifier 'com.xxx.xxx’ is correct"

I've checked my app bundle id and developer team are correct both in xcode and itunes.

And the most interesting thing is that my coworker loaded **the same build** with **the same account** successfully. 
In addition, I can easily load all other apps in itunes

What can be cause this error?

I've seen the answers, which say that I should use Application Loader, but it's missing in my xcode 11.3

P.S. Sorry for my english, it's not my native language

Comment: Did you try to disabling and enabling back the "Automatically manage signing" option in the project settings?

Comment: I guess you can use [this app](https://apps.apple.com/by/app/transporter/id1450874784?mt=12) for MacOS and try to load your app, also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30110757/xcode-error-when-uploading-to-app-store-no-suitable-application-records-were-f)